# What is the worst effect of not using any master nodes in elasticsearch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

We want to use elasticsearch for our service. It is mostly recommended in Production, we should use master nodes. What is the worst that could happen if we don’t use master nodes? It is increasing the cost of our cluster and we don’t see the purpose of them so much. Thats why asking. Our cluster would be just 200 GB with 2 data nodes of m4.large.

Comment: What you mean by don't use master node? when you have a cluster one node should have info about shards and which shards is allocated in which node , that's what node master do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any of your data nodes as a master node as well if you don't want to have dedicated master nodes. Although its recommended to have a separate small size master node for fault-tolerance(and in your case you can even use the micro instances for that purpose which have faster persistent storage like SSD as that's where cluster state is stored, more info [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-node.html#master-node)).

But as it's just a best practice and you can still use any of your data nodes as the master node(if you handle all the corner cases properly like when that data node goes down, another data node should be elected as master in your case etc.) and more information on this can be found [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-node.html#modules-node). But in short, if you want to have the same node act as data and master node then use below settings in node elasticsearch.yml:

```
node.master: true
node.data: true
```